# Как убрать пробелы в строке

Tags: строки, golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var letter1, letter2 byte
    var text string
    fmt.Scanf("%c\n%c\n%s", &letter1)
    fmt.Scanf("%c\n%c\n%s", &letter2)
    fmt.Scan(&text)
    count1 := 0
    count2 := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(text); i++ {
        if text[i] == letter1 {
            count1++
        } else if text[i] == letter2 {
            count2++
        }
    }

    if count1 > count2 {
        fmt.Printf("%c %d\n%c %d", letter1, count1, letter2, count2)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%c %d\n%c %d", letter2, count2, letter1, count1)
    }
}
```

мы вводить 2 буквы, например o и e, а также предложение. Пример: o
e   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, нужно подсчитать сколько раз используются буквы o и e в этом предложении. Как можно сделать чтобы из the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog получилось: thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog

Comment: Как я только что выяснил в гугле -- `"Golang strings are immutable, which means that they cannot be changed once they have been initialized."`. Поэтому для удаления пробелов вам придется построить новую строку

Answer (score 0):

```
randomString := "  hello      this is a test"
fmt.Println(strings.ReplaceAll(randomString, " ", ""))

>hellothisisatest
```

Просто заменяем все пробелы пустой строкой